# JSON To Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm Using Swift2.0+, SwiftyJSON, Alamofire

I Got the Value `let stringJSON:JSON = ["a1","a2","a3"]` from Server

But If I Check `stringJSON[0]`,Then it's `null`

When I `debugPrint(stringJSON)`, Then it's `["a1","a2","a3"]`

How Can I got the value `stringJSON[0] //"a1"` ?

Do I Have To Convert From JSON To Another?

Comment: Are you sure `stringJSON` it's a array and not a simple `String`? Maybe something like this `"["a1","a2","a3"]"` and not this `["a1","a2","a3"]`?

Comment: I checked. `debugPrint(stringJSON is JSON)` is `true` and `debugPrint(stringJSON)` is `["a1","a2","a3"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
let stringJSON:JSON = ["a1","a2","a3"]

if let firstValue = stringJSON.array?.first {
    print(firstValue) // a1
}
```

### Update

Since the value actually contains this string `"[\"a1\/a1\",\"a2\/a2\",\"a3\"]"` and you cannot fix this on the server side here it is a workaround.

```
if let words = stringJSON.string?.characters.dropFirst().dropLast().split(",").map(String.init) {
    let word = String(words[0].characters.dropFirst().dropLast())
    print(word) // a1
}
```

Comment: The Code Works Perfect. But In My Code Value `stringJSON.array` returns `nil`.

Comment: @Yoohogyun: So it's not an array. You have something else inside your `JSON`. If you try my code (where `stringJSON` actually contains an array) in Playground it will work.

Comment: Yes I Tried That. That Working On. But When I Got the Data From Server(Using Alamofire) Then, stringJSON.array Not Working On. Any Thing else?

Comment: You must check the server. It's not sending you an array. Please let me see your full JSON in plain text.

Comment: `{
  "data" : {
    "categories" : "[\"a1\/a1\",\"a2\/a2\",\"a3\"]",
    "positions" : "개발자\/디자인\/기획자",
    "period" : "2016-03-25T15:00:00.000Z",
    "recruitment" : 3,
    "members" : 0,
    "appliers" : 0,
    "clips" : 1,
    "contests_id" : 119,
    "cont_writer" : 1043580549047333,
    "title" : "sdf13",
    "postdate" : "2016-02-25T20:31:37.000Z",
    "is_finish" : 0,
    "cover" : "213123",
    "username" : "유호균",
    "hosts" : "213",
    "views" : 99
  },
  "result" : true,
  "msg" : "상세 목록 가져옴"
}` And I Want to `JSON["data"]["categories"]` to Array

Comment: As I suspected the server is sending you a `String` for categories. Not an array.

Comment: If I should Using That, Do I Have To Convert String To NSArray?, Have Any Idea about easiest Way?

Comment: Edited Answer works Perfect! Thanks for Your concern

Answer (score 1):

```
if let x = stringJSON[0].string{
print(x)
}
```

Comment: compile Error. Error Message here. `Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'String' `

Comment: @Yoohogyun It's `.string` and everything you need to know is already in the  examples on GitHub: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#subscript

Comment: @EricD gah! I was so close

Comment: i've read them. but I Mean The JSON To JSON Array. The Document Has Only NSArray To JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Since the server is not returning an Array, but a String, you need to convert that into an Array of Strings like this:

```
let string = stringJSON.string
let array = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[", withString: "")
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]", withString: "")
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
    .componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

stringJSONIf it is a string type, you can like this to solve:

```
extension String {

var parseJSONString: AnyObject? {
    var any: AnyObject?
    let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    do{
        any = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
    return any
}
```

and use it like this:

```
let strArr = stringJSON.stringvalue.parseJSONString as! Array<String>
```

Comment: First, you want to make sure it is a type string array,like this:   "[\"a1\/a1\",\"a2\/a2\",\"a3\"]"  The need to parse